# How to see more items in Delphi7 "View Unit" frame?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

I'm working in Delphi 7 on a project which as of late contains 56 units and will require a dozen more soon. I'm often switching between units using **View Unit** frame (Ctrl+F12). But it has one annoying flaw - the frame is rather small, it fits only 20 items. I have to scroll up and down to select unit I need to work on.

What are the solutions to make working with such many units easier? I'm especially looking forward to a patch or tweak to allow me to make **View Unit** frame taller, but I would like to avoid complex and/or costly plug-ins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC in Delphi 7 you can type the name of the unit in the view unit, or the name of the form in the view form dialogs.  Delphi XE contains filtering functionality.

Comment: I would like to see all the files myself, to select the right one, instead of typing its name by memory

Comment: You don't need to type the whole name, just the first couple of characters.

Comment: I don't use GExperts, but RRUZ answer looks like what you need.  For some monitors, it will be just impossible to see all files, my secondary vertical monitor is only 24", but RAD usually runs on the primary monitor, also 24", but horizontal, so I'm glad to get filtering support, that way I can write anything in the file name to get a partial relevant list.

Comment: CTRL+F12 for list (index) of units … and Ctrl-G for list (index) of functions / procedures in that code file ..
(CTRL+Fn+F12) on a Dell through RDP ..  (Fn+F12 kidnapped by Dell from brightness or volume)
https://superuser.com/questions/1348273/how-to-use-f3-function-key-on-dell-inspiron-13-laptop#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using the `View Units` of the <strike>[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/download.html)</strike> [`CnPack`](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=689&lang=en)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's not working for Delphi7. I went through all options and there's no "Unit List" nor enhanced IDE forms work :(

Comment: This window is part of the `GExperts` plugin and replaces the standard “View Unit” when you press Ctrl+F12. also the screenshot if of a Delphi 7 project with 724 units with the GExperts installed.

Comment: I've downloaded version 1.34 version from your link, but for some weird reason it does not show this "Unit List" frame in Delphi 7 I have.

Comment: Sorry I must say CnPack. i have both plugins installed in my system.(check the link http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=689&lang=en)

Answer (score 2):

I find the [GExperts Open File expert](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?openfile.html) very convenient.

[image: Screenshot of the GExperts Open File expert]